# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cne' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got an error while saving data.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cne' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `students` (`cne`, `firstName`, `secondName`, `age`, `speciality`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-04-03 20:47:34, 2020-04-03 20:47:34))
```

I wonder what I could do to fix that.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/',"StudentController@index") ;
Route::get('/edit/{id}',"StudentController@edit") ;
Route::get('/show/{id}',"StudentController@show") ;
Route::get('/create',"StudentController@create") ;
Route::get('/store',"StudentController@store") ;
Route::get('/update/{id}',"StudentController@update") ;
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {

        $student = new Student() ;
        $student->cne = $request->input('cne') ;
        $student->firstName = $request->input('firstName') ;
        $student->secondName = $request->input('secondName') ;
        $student->age = $request->input('age') ;
        $student->speciality = $request->input('speciality') ;
        $student->save() ;
        return redirect('/') ;
        //
    }
```

**HTML**

```
@if($layout == 'index') 

        <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <div class="row">
                <selctio class="col">
                @include("studentslist")
                </selction>
            <selction class="col"></selction>
            </div>          
        </div>

  @elseif($layout == 'create')
        <div class="container-fluid" id="create-form">
            <div class="row">
                <selctio class="col">
                    @include("studentslist")
                </selction>
                <selction class="col">
                    <form action="{{ url('/store') }}" method="POST" >
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>CNE</label>
                            <input name="cne" id="cne" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter cne">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter the first name">
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>second Name</label>
                            <input name="secondName" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter second name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Age</label>
                            <input name="age" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter the Age">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Speciality</label>
                            <input name="speciality" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Sepeciality">
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">                       
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset">
                    </form>
                </selction>
            </div>         
        </div>

  @elseif($layout == 'show')
        <div class="container-fluid">  
                <div class="row">
                    <selctio class="col">
                        @include("studentslist")
                    </selction>
                    <selction class="col"></selction>
                </div>
        </div>
  @elseif($layout == 'edit')
        <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col-md-7">
                    @include("studentslist")
                </section>
                <section class="col-md-5">                    

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
  @endif
```

Comment: Verify what `$request` contains in your controller and if all your data is being posted. I suspect it's not coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "1048 Column' cannot be null" error is triggered when a column.. cannot be null.

You should take a look at your migration file. Add the nullable method like this:

```
$table->string('cne')->nullable();
```

If you do not want to rewrite your migration, you will need to use something like that:

```
$table->string('cne')->nullable()->change();
```

Futhermore, change the Route file so that the store route uses the post method:

```
Route::post('/store',"StudentController@store") ;
```

Comment: `cne` is in his HTML and his Controller... he probably intends to fill it. Making it nullable will likely suppress the real error.

Comment: @izzathali what do you get with dd($request->input('cne') ) in the controller ?

Comment: Kernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.  this error is coming. when i click http://127.0.0.1:8000/store for more details it displays null.

Comment: @izzathali See updated answer. Check the route file.